# How to build regex for complex Indonesian phone number format?

Tags: regex, phone-number

Recently, i am using [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) to build this custom regex.
I am working with several test case for Indonesian phone number.

Here an example for the simple one `08xx-3456-7890` or `08xx34567890`

but it can be a bit confusing if i get this following format

```
here is my phone (08xx)34567890
08xx.3456.7890
08xx 3456 7890
(+62) 8xx34567890
(+62) 8xx-3456-7890
+628xx34567890
+62-8xx-3456-7890
+628xx 3456 7890
```

here is regex i have done with `(08|628|62)[\s\)\-]*(\s|(\d){3,})`
but i can not cover all of those sample.

> +62 is country code

Can you please help me with any solution to validate those format?

> the phone number is possible contains string instead just number, because it is part of sentence

Comment: i'm not sure why that dude down vote this, without any comment

Comment: Piece of advice: start by splitting the parts into four logical groups of `(+62)`, `8xx`, `3456`, `7890`, then work on the variations individually before putting your whole regex pattern together

Comment: What's `x`? Any number? Are `34567890` any number too?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen see my edit sir, because it is not just number, some times it is followed by string of sentence.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais yes `x` is number and `34567890` should be just a number

Comment: I would worry about the delimiters separately

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen can you start from this https://regex101.com/r/kwZdKU/5 ?

Comment: I don't get the "xx" at all, nor the 62. If x is a number, then why is it an x.  What is your **goal** (ie, what are you trying to match) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to remove tokens first with regex `[().- ]` and replace with empty string. Then you can use [`(?:\+62)?0?8\d{2}(\d{8})`](https://regex101.com/r/VzdtPe/2) to match a phone number. This matches an optional `+62`, an optional `0`, `8`, two digits (`xx`) and the phone number: 8 digits. Group 1 contains the phone number.

Comment: this can be one of solution, but not the efficient one. thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Indonesian phone numbers, this roughly should work.

```
(\()?(\+62|62|0)(\d{2,3})?\)?[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}
```

To see it in action:
https://regex101.com/r/qtEg6H/3

Also see the answer in the comment below for a more efficient way.

Comment: your match groups are changing with each match.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new in regex. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: use `(?:...)` if you don't care about the match groups: see this slightly cleaner version: `\(?(?:\+62|62|0)(?:\d{2,3})?\)?[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}[ .-]?\d{2,4}` https://regex101.com/r/qtEg6H/4

Comment: Thanks, that does seems simpler with the same result. You learn new thing everyday.

Answer (score 0):

// MARK: - Validate Indonesia Mobile Number Without Country Code 
//The number should be start by 8 digit character

```
class func validateMobileNumber(_ number: String) -> Bool {
    let numberRegEx = "[8][0-9]{10,14}"
    let numberTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegEx)
    if numberTest.evaluate(with: number) == true {
        return true
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```