# Regex for Indonesian phone number

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that can accept the following number format.

```
+62 361 222777
+62 813-444-5555
+62 812-3333-3333
+62 811 391 2103
+62 361-2277777
(0361) 227337
+62 8113912103
08134455555
0361-2277777 (*)
+62 812 3333 3333 (*)
+62 877 80803550 (*)
081339222111 (*)
081 339 222 111 (*)
+62 811338429196 (*)
```

Here is what I did so far:

```
\+62\s\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3}[-\.\s]??\d{3,4}|\(0\d{2,3}\)\s?\d+|0\d{2,3}\s?\d{6,7}|\+62\s?361\s?\d+|\+62\d+|\+62\s?(?:\d{3,}-)*\d{3,5}
```

The last six numbers (indicated by *) is not fully found by the regular expression I have above. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of implementing this as a **crazy-complicated** (and almost certainly wrong) regular expression, why not just relax the rules? If it's vitally important that the number is correct, you should be sending a confirmation phone call/text message anyway (which makes the regex check redundant!).

Comment: See [How to build regex for complex Indonesian phone number format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536267/how-to-build-regex-for-complex-indonesian-phone-number-format)

Comment: Check  https://regex101.com/r/TrLmiC/1

Comment: Why do you do not make it preg_replace('/[0-9]/', '', $no) before? Then it is much easier.

Comment: Wiktor solution seems to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My advice would be to try breaking problem into smaller ones.

You can solve like this:

```
(\+62 ((\d{3}([ -]\d{3,})([- ]\d{4,})?)|(\d+)))|(\(\d+\) \d+)|\d{3}( \d+)+|(\d+[ -]\d+)|\d+
```

You can see demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/mSP6kY/5). I've broke problem into smaller ones divided like this `()|()|...`, so you can see what cases I was solving by deleting individual brackets.

Even easier way is:

```
\+?([ -]?\d+)+|\(\d+\)([ -]\d+)
```

You can see this version [here](https://regex101.com/r/vyTOpe/1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for all the number.

Comment: I add non capturing group in each bracket. 
    \+?(?:[ -]?\d+)+|\(\d+\)(?:[ -]\d+)

Comment: Hi Aleksandar, it accepts 80361 also which is a zip code. How do you restrict this?

Comment: You can add quantifiers with a minimum of 7 or 8 to restrict zip code `{7,}`